# How can cut the time it takes to tag videos using Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, video, tags

When I try to tag a video using windows explorer it takes roughly 10-20 seconds for it to complete. If I try to tag multiple videos using the same tag it takes even longer? How can I cut this time down.

I am currently using Windows 7 Home Premium; Processor: AMD Athlon II x2 250 (3.00 GHz); Ram 3.00 GB. My files are located on an external hard drive, a WD western digital My Book 3 TB.

Comment: I think a 3rd party program would do the job.